# Evaluating a limit?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. Evaluate $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+2015h)-f(x+2014h)}{h}$.

So, I was thinking of making the substitution $y=x+2014h$. So then it becomes $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h}$ which is just f'(y), but I have a feeling that this isn't what the question is asking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: You set $y=x+2014h$ and then evaluate the limit as $y$ does not depend on $h$.

Comment: If $y=x+2014h$ then of course $y$ depends on h.

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons that's the OP's problem.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't make that substitution then.

Comment: @1---011 I'm just showing you why didn't your substitution work.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstood you,  sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a non-Taylor series way of evaluating, 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2015h) - f(x+2014h)}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f(x+2015h) - f(x)}{h} -  \frac{f(x+2014h) - f(x)}{h} \right) \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+2015h) - f(x)}{h} - \, \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2014h) - f(x)}{h} \\
&= 2015 \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+2015h) - f(x)}{2015h} - \, 2014\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2014h) - f(x)}{2014h} \\
&= 2015 f'(x) - 2014 f'(x) \\
&= f'(x).
\end{align*}

Comment: Nothing could be better than this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor expansion
\begin{align*}
& \frac{f(x + 2015h) - f(x + 2014h)}{h} \\ 
= &\frac{[f(x) + f'(x)(2015h) + o(h)]  - [f(x) + f'(x)(2014h) + o(h)]}{h} \\
= & \frac{f'(x)h + o(h)}{h} \\ 
= & f'(x) + o(1) \to f'(x)
\end{align*}
as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Oh okay, what is o(h)?

Comment: $o(h)$ is a notation of Peano's remainder satisfying $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{o(h)}{h} = 0$. Also known as "the little $o$" notation, which is extensively used in calculus.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. Is there a way to evaluate this without using the taylor expansion?

Comment: yes, use add and subtract trick